# For Android fusion chart showing html content in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, graph, fusioncharts

I have integrated fusion chart to my application in React Native. For iOS, Its working fine, But, In android while I tried to display graph, Its showing html content in the UI.

I have followed installation steps properly from github page.

> //header declaration

```
const fusionChartiOSPath = require('../assets/fusioncharts.html');

const fusionChartAndroidPath = { uri: 'file:///android_asset/fusioncharts.html' };
```

> //render method

```
      <FusionCharts
        type={type}
        width={width}
        height={height}
        dataFormat={dataFormat}
        dataSource={dataSource}
        containerBackgroundColor={containerBackgroundColor}
        libraryPath={
          Platform.OS === 'ios'
            ? fusionChartiOSPath
            : fusionChartAndroidPath
       }
      />
```

But, In UI its showing like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
....
```

Can anyone suggest me, Where I am doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's happening due to some file issue.  Fixed

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. can you pls share how this issue was resolved?